# send image to rest service xamarin forms

Tags: c#, image, rest, web-services, xamarin.forms

I'm trying, without success, to send an image from Xamarin Forms to a Rest WebApi. I'm using CrossMedia plugin by Montemagno. I converted the MediaFile to base64String in this way:

```
if (photo != null)
{
    var stream = photo.GetStream();
    var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
    await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
    string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    Task<string> sendFotoResult = restClient.SendImage(imageBase64);
    string result = await sendFotoResult;
    if( ... )
}
```

this is my SendImage function:

```
public async Task<string> SendImage(string foto)
{
  try
  {
     // METHOD 1 
     var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foto);
     string url = "http://myaddress/myWS/api/Home/SendImage?foto="+ content;
     var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
     return response.ReasonPhrase.ToString();

     //METHOD 2
     var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foto);
     string url = "http://myaddress/myWS/api/Home/SendImage?foto="+ content;
     var result = await _client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
     return result.ToString(); 
  }catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return ex.Message;
  }
}
```

method 1 show null parameter error, method 2 get URL too long error.

How I can fix it? 
Is convert image to base64String best way to send it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Sending an image within the query string is a very bad idea.

Comment: this my first time, I guess there are many many better ways to do this, I just asked them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not sent the image on the URI. What you have to do is to send the image on the body of your request. Something like this will help you:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(new MemoryStream(foto).ToArray()), "foto", "foto.jpg");
```

Then you have to manage the image on your server side api and convert it back.

EDIT: I assume that if you also control your REST api, then you must be trying to get the image from the uri. You should not do that, but instead what you have to do is get it from the content. Here is a tutorial that will lead you though all the way: https://jamessdixon.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/handling-images-in-webapi/

Also, you should call your POST method without parameters like this:

```
string url = "http://myaddress/myWS/api/Home/"
```

If you already manage POST on Home controller to do some other work then you can always make use of a routing and call something like this:

```
string url = "http://myaddress/myWS/api/Home/Images/"
```

Routing on ASP.NET is very simple to manage and it is very well described on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Finally, I suspect that you might need to reinforce your REST knowledge on what standards concern. I always recomend the following page to understand what should and shouldn´t be done designing a RESTful API: http://blog.octo.com/en/design-a-rest-api/

Comment: maybe use of MultipartFormDataContent() is the right way. How to write the URL in correct way?

Comment: sure, I have reinforce my REST knowledge you're right. Is my first approach with this and the road is still looong. Before this, how you suggest me to fix it?

Comment: although you disappeared your links are very usefull. I solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultipartFormDataContent to add the image part to the post request, try this example

```
            var upfilebytes = DependencyService.Get<ILocalFileProvider>().GetFileBytes(FileUrl);
            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            ByteArrayContent baContent = new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);
            content.Add(baContent, "File", "attachment.png");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```